# need popup window inside a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple website which is written by php and mysql code. i have a detect button on my my sql table query  page and given below code is writen for this function but my problem is i need a popup window when the detect link is clicked. i have tired to set a code in my created code but i am not able .kindly please help me solve this problem.

```
    <?php $sezione="home_admin"; if(isset($_POST['messaggio']))
$messaggio=$_POST['messaggio']; 
include("control_admin..php");
 $canc_id=$_GET['canc_id']; 
$idcorsocanc=$_POST['idcorsocanc']; 
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];?>
        <?php 
        /*echo "permessi".$permessi;
        echo "<br>id".$id_nome;*/

        if($action=='canc'){?>
            <h1>are you sure want to delect the course?</h1>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="canc1" style="float: left; margin-left:25px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="idcorsocanc" value="<?=$canc_id?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Si,cancella" class="puls_invia">
        </form>

        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" name="canc2" style="float: left; margin-left:25px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="NO" class="puls_invia">
        </form>
        <?php
        }
```

ok i want to update my question cause i follow one answer and here the code is-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ok').click(function(){
        if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
            $('#form').submit();
        }else{
            return false;       
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if($_POST['action'] == 'deleted'){
        //the form has been sent, do something
    }
}else{
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="button" id="ok" name="ok" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="deleted">
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

but till now my problem is i alreday have link name delect and if i click that link i saw another delete button cause now i use the following code which i just update then if i click there i saw the pop up window but if i click ok that course is not delete cause i guess something is missing.

my actual need is i alreday have delect link and i need something that if i click on that i saw one opoup window.just this is my need.

Comment: Question title exploded my brains. It seems "HTML table" meant

Comment: Well u still have to replace `//the form has been sent, do something` with some PHP codes that connects to the DB and deletes the record. U should add an extra hidden field with the id of the course u want to delete tho

Comment: thanks for ur answer but as i told that i m not very expert in php and got get the point how i shoudl write the code inset of  //the form has been sent, do something// plz if possible saw my very 1st php code and that is the actual code which is conect with my db. so i need soemthing form my very 1st given php code.if possible answer me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client-side script to manage this.  I'd recommend something in jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".myButton").click(triggerPopup); 

})

function triggerPopup(){
//do popup stuff 
}

</script>
```

an example in more details can be found by googling.  something like this http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/

Comment: anyway i am new in website development sector.may be my question tittle  has some error.but that is not important i think.if someone is very expert they should help me from my description and see my code.this is 2nd time i ask this question and i am realy upset that people are just try to hit each other without solve the problem. anyway your guess is right.i want some thing like when i should click delect link for a permission ."are you sure want to delect" this line should be comes a popup window .now if i click i saw this line visible in my home page. @mjayt

Comment: @sanny, well it is important to make yourself clear so we can give proper aid. Don't forget if javascript is not enabled the user will be able to delete every record w/out confirmation.

Comment: yes @ darkbee you are right.but till now i am not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Well if u want that popup window you should definitely use javascript, preferable jquery. Update your question with some updated code of what u tried

Comment: hi @DarkBee i already update my answer kindly help if u get my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in javascript. Especially with jquery library

This should look like this :

```
<?php 
include("control_admin.php");
$sezione = "home_admin"; 
$canc_id = $_GET['canc_id']; //i'm gessing this is the ID to delete ?
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ok').click(function(){
        if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
            $('#form').submit();
        }else{
            return false;       
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if($_POST['action'] == 'deleted'){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = "delete from table_name where column_id = ".$id;
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo $canc_id . ' has been deleted!';
    }
}else{
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="button" id="ok" name="ok" value="Delete">
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="deleted">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?=$canc_id?>">
</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, your answer is very useful i mean it works but the problem is it has no conection with my code cause as u saw my php code.casue when i click for delect my course for which i already write some sql query but it didnot cencel.i mean i just saw a delect button and the pop up window but if i click ok for delete my course i am not able to delete that course.could plz help me for this case.@ yves

Comment: Hi, yes, you have to add the php code with your sql query in here :   if($_POST['action'] == 'deleted'){
        //the form has been sent, do something
    }

Comment: hi. thanks a lot again @yves but the problem is i alreday have one query for delect the course and i need pop up window form there .but if i add ur code in my index.php page .when i go to my home page i saw another delect button and that has no link with my database where the course name and delete link is already i had.plz if u have any commnet about this tell me.

Comment: hi i am sorry that i ask very basic question but alreday i metioned i m new thats why some part goes very tough for me .form your query i guess my id shoulde be -  $sql = "delete from table_name where column_id = ".$idcorsocanc; but if i add this my webpage block.

Comment: plz follow this code if possible- <?php
$sezione="home_admin";
if(isset($_POST['messaggio']))$messaggio=$_POST['messaggio'];
include("control_admin..php"); 
$canc_id=$_GET['canc_id'];
$idcorsocanc=$_POST['idcorsocanc'];
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; this code was written my index.php page start code
?>

Comment: Well please post your entire page code in the question section

Comment: And you should maybe read some tutorials about how html/php formulars work.

Comment: Try with my code.. If it doesn't work then sorry but don't understand how you access this page..

Comment: hi @yves this is not only one page i have more page for this work.i mean i just add here start of my page code with my problem .how i add my code in my question now my page is written same in my site also.and after this code i ahve some query with one table.

Comment: till now i was not able to solve my problem .is there anyone solve this?